# Armadillo Mat::save() couldn't write to FILE

Tags: load, save, mat, armadillo

I am trying to save a matrix which has about 768 rows and only 4-5 columns with all entries filled. The matrix is of the type `Mat<double>`. Using the `save` method, I tried to save the matrix as a CSV in the following way:

```
dg.save("dg_file.csv", csv_ascii);
```

But it fails giving me an error:

`Mat::save(): couldn't write to dg_file.csv`

The same happens when I use `load` function for this matrix after having written the file in an alternative, inefficient way. Please note that both the functions work fine with matrices of smaller size. I did not find any mention about size limitations for matrices in using these functions. Later, I plan to use the code for slightly larger matrices in the order of 10,000 rows and columns.

Also, please suggest any alternative methods of saving and loading in Armadillo.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue and do you have the solution I am having same problem now

Comment: Sorry, it has been so long, I don't recall whether I fixed the issue or adopted something else. I looked through my work from that time, but don't seem to find anything relevant to this issue.

Comment: I found the solution to this using save to put in a txt file and later using the file further thanks for the response